# Intersecting geotiff with another one using alpha-channel (or nodata value) in GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, intersection

I have two geotiffs related to one location but with different areas covered:

1.

[image: The first geotiff]

2.

[image: The second geotiff]

How can I intersect their opaque parts into single geotiff like that?

[image]

Comment: what are the nodata vaues of 1. and 2.?

Comment: @RoVo let it be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This solution is working for single band image only**

If you have multiple bands, you may repeat this for each band adding `-A_Band` and `-B_Band` options and then `gdal_merge.py -separate` the bands.

---

You should be able to do this:

(We assume NoData Value of your rasters is `0`)

```
gdal_calc.py -A file1.tif -B file2.tif --NoDataValue=0 \
--calc="A*(A>0)+B*logical_and(A==0,B>0)" \
--outfile=outfile.tif
```

Explanation:

- `A*(A>0)`: if A is not Nodata, will be `A*1`, else `A*0`
- `B*logical_and(A==0,B>0)`: if A is NoData and B is not Nodata, will be `B*1`, else `B*0`.

(This will always prefer A over B).

Comment: I think I need to transform both images to the save window before doing math.

Comment: *to the same window

Comment: I might need to change a bit as this works for single band GeoTiff. I'll update later